# Does the rigorous limit definition give rise to the same concept if we consider an $l^p$ metric ($p\geq2$) as the distance function?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Does the $\varepsilon\!\!-\!\!\delta$ limit definition give rise to he same concept if we consider an $l^p$ metric ($p\geq2$) as the distance function?

In other words, do we obtain the same concept and same results if we define limits instead as: for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is some $\delta>0$ such that if $0<d_{l^p}(x,a)<\delta \implies 0<d_{l^p}(f(x),L)<\varepsilon$.

If not, then what about considering instead having the $l^p$ in only one part, like: for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is some $\delta>0$ such that if $0<|x-a|<\delta\implies 0<d_{l^p}(f(x),L)<\varepsilon$. **OR** for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is some $\delta>0$ such that if $0<d_{l^p}(x,a)<\delta$ then $0<|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$.

Furthermore does this apply to the multivariable version of the above definitions?

Comment: What do you men by concept ? Do you mean it induces the same topology ?

Comment: @G.F No, I mean does it yield the same limit concept, i.e. will we get the same results if we use the new limit formulation that I mentioned?

Comment: In general, different metrics (topologies) yield different limits unless they are equivalent metrics (topologies). What space are you on btw? $\mathbb{R}$? (Usually $l^p$ denotes the metric on the space of sequences, but maybe you meant $L^p$)

Comment: @Harnak Yes $\mathbb{R}$ where $l^p$ is $(|x_i-y_i|^p+\cdots+|x_n-y_n|^p)^{1/p}$. If that's the case then I'd be interested in some example, also what about the second part of my question where only one part of the implication is formulated using the $l^p$ distance?

Comment: This is true. Also for multivariable, i.e. $\mathbb{R}^n$. The topologies induced by the $p$- norm, and euclidean norm are equivalent. You can show that all the open sets in one topology are open in the other topology. It's enough to show that every open ball in one topology contains an open ball in the other topology, I'll leave this to you.

Comment: @Kolja thanks, so it works even if only either side has the different $l^p$ formulation (i.e. if $0<|x-a|<\delta\implies 0<d_{l^p}(f(x),L)<\varepsilon$. **OR** for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is some $\delta>0$ such that if $0<d_{l^p}(x,a)<\delta$ then $0<|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$)? I wonder what about if one side has say an $l^4$ formulation while the other has an $l^6$ one, will your proof technique (which I haven't thought about yet) still work?